# Angular js UI grid is not getting updated with new content

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am calling $http.get to get new content from the server for angular ui grid. On change of date in the datepicker I trigger an ng-change event to make another http call to get new content. The call is successful but the grid is not updated with new content.$scope.grid.core.notifyDataChange() throws error when called inside the http success call back.Please suggest ways to update the grid with new content.

Please find the plnkr code. when I click load button, I want to update grid with new JSON data using http call but it is not updating grid. http://plnkr.co/edit/S2A3scEoO6QIGFbru3Lr?p=preview

Comment: Please provide the code you are using so someone may be able to help.

Comment: You need to add some code, what did you try?

Comment: Please find the plnkr code. when I click load button, I want to update grid with new JSON data using http call but it is not updating grid. http://plnkr.co/edit/S2A3scEoO6QIGFbru3Lr?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your example is inside `$http`'s `success` method(lines 256-260).

```
$http.get(...).success(
  function(data){
    $scope.roData = data;
});
```

There you are just putting your data inside a scope property (`$scope.roData`), but then you're not doing anything with that scope property.

Furthermore you're trying to assign a wrong value to `uiGrid.gridOptions.data` with the lines:

```
if($scope.gridOptions.data ==='rData'){
  $scope.gridOptions.data = 'roData';
}
```

But you did 2 mistakes:

1. Treating variables as string, and this is not going to work. Inside your JS files you need to access your scope with `$scope.nameOfVariable` not by using their names as strings like `'nameOfVariable'`.
2. You put these lines outside of your `success` method, so they are executed before you actually get your data.

I managed to edit your plunker and make it work, you can find it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/lvbuiGlpmQiCsqP9fjci?p=preview). 
What I did was putting your lines together and fix the name error. I did not put there any `if` since I don't know what logic you wanted to accomplish.

```
$http.get(...).success(
  function(data){
    $scope.roData = data;
    $scope.gridOptions.data = $scope.roData;
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.